# Javascript bookmark, find check boxes by value

Tags: javascript, checkbox, bookmarks

I have a lengthy script that has broken in a recent OS update. The bookmark script, when run throws a pop up window that you can enter order numbers in to. It searches for those orders, checks the boxes applicable, bolds them, and then displays a list of orders that were found and orders that were not found.

Since the update nothing is found, it only displays orders as not being found.

```
javascript:q=prompt("ORDER NUMBERS","");
q=q.toUpperCase();
allOrders=q;
allOrders=allOrders.replace(/[^\w]/g,' ');
allOrders=allOrders.replace(/\b(?!M)\w+\b/g,' ');
allOrders=allOrders.replace(/ +/g,' ');
nonOrders=allOrders;
foundOrders="";
nonOrders=nonOrders.replace(/[^\w]/g,' ');
elmz=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
refundAmount=0.00;
j=0;
for(var i=0; i<elmz.length; i++)
  {
  if(elmz[i].getAttribute("class")=="WebOrderNumber")
  {
  orderNum=elmz[i].innerHTML;
  orderNum=orderNum.replace(/<b>/g, '');
  orderNum=orderNum.replace(/<\/b>/g, '');
  if(q.indexOf(orderNum)!="-1")
  {
  var reOrder = new RegExp(orderNum, "g");
  foundOrders=foundOrders+orderNum+'\n';
  nonOrders=nonOrders.replace(reOrder,'');
  elmz[i].innerHTML="<b>"+ elmz[i].innerHTML+"</b>";
  elmzz=document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  k=0;
  for(var l=0; l<elmzz.length; l++)
  {
  if(elmzz[l].getAttribute("class")=="total")
  {
  if(k==j)
  {
  refundAmount=refundAmount+parseFloat(elmzz[l].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML);
  }
  k++;
  }
  }
  }
  j++;
  }
  }
if(refundAmount.toFixed(2)!="0.00")
  {
  alert(refundAmount.toFixed(2));
  }
else
  {
  more=true;
  while(more)
  {
  more=false;
  elmzzz=document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for(var i=0; i<elmzzz.length; i++)
  {
  if(elmzzz[i].getAttribute("class")=="sortable itemWebOrderNumber")
  {
  if(q.indexOf(elmzzz[i].innerHTML) != "-1")
  {
  var reOrder = new RegExp(elmzzz[i].innerHTML, "g");
  foundOrders=foundOrders+elmzzz[i].innerHTML+'\n';
  nonOrders=nonOrders.replace(reOrder,'');
  elmzzz[i].innerHTML="<b>"+elmzzz[i].innerHTML+"</b>";
  elmzzz[i-1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].click();
  more=true;
  }
  }
  }
  }
  }
nonOrders=nonOrders.replace(/ +/g,'\n');
alert("Found Orders:\n"+foundOrders+"\nPossible order numbers not located:\n"+nonOrders);
```

Comment: And which bit has broken?

Comment: I'm honestly not entirely certain. The pop up window still appears, but the results are blank, even though content is being entered that it should find. So in the instance here if I typed in 123456789 in the pop up it would find the check box next to that bit of text and check it ``<td class="sortable itemWebOrderNumber"> 123456789 </td>``